# drupal create product categories assign product to categories

Tags: drupal, categories, ubercart, product

I am new to Drupal.
I am using Drupal7 and Ubercart for e-commerce.
I created products.
Now,I wish to categorize them.
That is,I want to group all mobile phones under 'Mobile Phones', all laptops under 'Laptops' etc. 
For this, I created a new taxonamy vocabulary 'Mobile Phones' and now I am stopped as I don't know how to assign my products to this group?
for example, how to assign 'Nokia Lumia 820'(one among my products) to the group 'Mobile Phones'?
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your product content type add field for category select in which select following options

```
LABEL : "name of field"
FIELD TYPE : "Term reference"
WIDGET : "Select list"
```

and when asked for field settings give your taxonomy as Vocabulary.